# Extract Public Id From Cloudinary URL

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary to host my media on the cloud for my NodeJS project.
To delete an image from the Clodinary Cloud, I need to pass a Public Id for that image, to the Cloudinary API.
I realised, Public ID is embedded into the url, **how to I extract it out from the URL**?

***Because, I don't want to store my data in this format :***

```
image : {
    url : `http://res.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/image/upload/v1647610701/rsorl4rtziefw46fllvh.png`,
    publicId : `rsorl4rtziefw46fllvh`
}
```

***Rather, I find it better to store it like this :***

```
image : `http://res.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/image/upload/v1647610701/rsorl4rtziefw46fllvh.png`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the method `extractPublicId` from the package `cloudinary-build-url`

```js
import { extractPublicId } from 'cloudinary-build-url'

const publicId = extractPublicId(
    "http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1312461204/sample.jpg"
  )
```

Documentation: https://cloudinary-build-url.netlify.app/usage/extractPublicId

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is to implement a funciton which extracts the publicId for every URL passed in as argument.

Here's the function :

```
const getPublicId = (imageURL) => imageURL.split("/").pop().split(".")[0];
```

*Edited after **@loic-vdb 's** suggestion*

**Explanation** :

1. It splits the string in an array using "/" as seperator.

   imageURL="http://res.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/image/upload/v1647610701/rsorl4rtziefw46fllvh.png";

becomes,

```
imageURL = [ 'http:',
  '',
  'res.cloudinary.com',
  'cloud_name',
  'image',
  'upload',
  'v1647610701',
  'rsorl4rtziefw46fllvh.png' ]
```

2. Next, pop the array (returns the last element of the array)

   imageURL = 'rsorl4rtziefw46fllvh.png';
3. Now, split this string into array using "." as seperator, we get :

   imageURL = [ 'rsorl4rtziefw46fllvh', 'png' ]
4. Finally select the 0th element that is our PublicId return that

   imageURL =  'rsorl4rtziefw46fllvh';

Comment: folders are part of the public as mentioned here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#using_the_public_id_to_organize_media_assets_in_folders so the public_id by essence is everything between the version component and the extension i.e:
`url.split("/").slice(7).join("/").split(".")[0];` as `7` is the index of the value after the version component.

Comment: @LoicVdB So, what you mean to say is, **imageURL.split("/")[7].split(".")[0]**
Right? The reason why I did what I did is to componsate for any future change to the URl, but after your suggestion it feels lke setting definate index values is better than performing a reverse. Thank you.

Comment: that's right - normally the 6 first values of your array won't change but the rest may as you can have folders and subfolders so you need to consider them all

Comment: Yeah, I realised that soon after. Since, the code have to componsate for the folder and subfolder, that's why opted for using pop(), instead of indexes.

Comment: Unfortunately your updated answer is still not valid for all cases @AdityaPandey. Folders are part of the ID as Loic VdB mentioned, which means they need to be included in the ID, so taking everything after the last `/` is not correct when folders are used. As well, filenames may contain multiple dots before the extension (e.g. "a.name.with.dots.jpg"), so splitting on `.` and taking the first item will not produce a valid ID in that case either. There are more variants too. Better to use something like cloudinary-build-url's `extractPublicId` like Maya Shavin has suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the answer by a Cloudinary support team member](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006941639/comments/360001255340)

> ... the public_id contains all folders and the last part of the public_id is the filename.

Here is what I tried and worked

```js
const path = require("path");

const getPublicId = (imageURL) => {
  const [, publicIdWithExtensionName] = imageURL.split("upload/");
  const extensionName = path.extname(publicIdWithExtensionName)
  const publicId = publicIdWithExtensionName.replace(extensionName, "")
  return publicId
};
```

especially for cases where you store your assets in folders

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Aditya Pandey wasn't working in my case because I had the period character in my filename so I had to revise the code:

```
const extractPublicId = (link: string) => {
  const dottedParts = link.split('/').pop()!.split('.');
  dottedParts.pop();
  return dottedParts.join('.');
};
```

This code extracts the part from last `/` to last `.` character. You don't need the `!` after `pop()` if you aren't using Typescript.